# How to expand a DIV to use the whole parent DIV height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="right_col" role="main" style="min-height: 647px;">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="page-title"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And "fill" class is:

```
.fill {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However, the DIV with "fill" class does not expand to its parent, that has a min-height of 647px. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Instead of giving `.right_col` a min-height, just give `.fill` the min-height of 647px.

Comment: Percentage-based heights require the parent to have a set height. Min-height doesn't achieve this because it isn't "set", the height can still vary. Try putting `display: flex;` on the `right_col` div.

Comment: Percentage heights require the parent element to have a defined height. Setting a fixed height isn't always the best.

Comment: Don't give right_col a 'min-height'. Simply make it 'height:647px'. Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oynx373c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for an element to fill to it's parent's height with a percentage, the parent itself must have an actual height set.

Which makes sense if you think about it. If it's child is growing it height, that stretches the parent, but that makes the child need to grow more, stretching the parent, etc. until the parent and child are infinitely tall. It's a bit tricky.

If you need a child to fill up some space that it's sibling caused, you can also try using `position: absolute` and `left`, `right`, `top`, and/or `bottom` to fill in the extra space, in some scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Percentage heights for elements in the normal document flow only work if the `height` (not `min-height`) of the parent element is known. In situations where the parent's height is, itself, a percentage, then that element's parent height must be known. This can go all the way up to the HTML element when heights are not explicitly set on all the ancestors.

```css
html, body { height:100%; }

.right_col {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  height: 647px;
}

.fill {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="page-title"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Every ancestor"_ is a bit misleading and only counts if each of those element's height is a percentage. If somewhere along the way a fixed height is used (or something that can be calculated into such like `rem` or `vh`), you'll be fine, i.e. `height: 300px; > height: 75%; > height: 50%;`.

Answer (score 3):

you may use flex;

```css
.right_col {
  min-height: 647px;
  display: flex;
}

.fill {
  flex: 1;
  background: gray;/* see me */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="fill">
    <div class="page-title">t</div>
    <div class="clearfix">clr</div>
    <div class="row">r</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.right_col {
  position: relative;
}
```

That's it. Child div will consider 100% with respect to its parent div.